# Can I use v-if with style tag to choose a different source file? Or is there a better alternative?

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, vue.js

I tried doing the example below, but it would not work. The reason why I am trying to do this is is that I would have to add way too many modifiers (--tuned) to make this work. So I was trying to source the css file based on a condition. Why would this not work and does anyone know if there is a better alternative that a million modifiers ?

```
<style v-if="!isTuningActive" lang="scss" src="./normal-version.scss"></style>
<style
  v-else
  lang="scss"
  src="./tuned-version.scss"
></style>
```

Comment: CSS files are usually loaded once, unloading them takes extra effort. It's a mistake to do this dynamically if you need to constantly switch between them.

Answer (score 1):

Why not separate into components? Each components with his own styling.

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html

Comment: I realise there's not enough info here, but it depends if the content of the component is the same or just the scss. You wouldn't want to maintain two identical components that just differ in styling.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile your separate scss files into a single stylesheet (main.scss for example), then just import that main.scss file into your parent component (likely, App.vue).

This will allow you to simply switch the css class on your example above instead of trying to conditionally import stylesheets.

For example, lets say your new 'main.scss' file contains the following scss.

```
.tuned-version {
   p { color: red }
}

.untuned-version {
   p { color: blue } 
}
```

Then you'll simply need to dynamically add the class depending on your **isTuningActive** property.

```
<div :class="isTuningActive ? 'tuned-version' : 'untuned-version">
    <p>My content</p>
</div>
```

Helpful references:

1. Compiling scss in Vue: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#sass
2. Dynamic class binding: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes